# virtualbox - how does default networking works inside virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox

So I am trying to configure a virtual network and all is working fine but what I cannot seem to understand is that how does the virtualbox `eth0` interface can by default `ping` my usb modem IP?
I did `traceroute 100.72.85.15` and it shows only two nodes one with the ip of `eth0` and other one, my modem.
So how does virtualbox achieves this? I tried docs but couldn't find anything related to it or useful!
My main purpose for asking this question is I want to configure on my host machine, a virtual interface say `eth1` and configure it with a private ip address in such a way that instead of directly talking to my modem the virtual machine talks to `eth1` and then `eth1` in turn talks to my modem.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox default networking configuration is NAT. It is well explained in this [chapter](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat).

It is unclear what you want to achieve with the eth1 interface but you will likely have routing problems if you go that way.

I would suggest [bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) instead if NAT is not suiting your needs for some reason.